# Delete specific file and copy file to folder using forfiles

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to delete a specific file from the folder (\10.0.1.223\ClamAV_DB) then paste in a file to the folder (\10.0.1.223\ClamAV_DB) from (C:\ProgramData.clamwin\db) using forfiles. But it seems not working. I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

```
FORFILES /P \\10.0.1.223\ClamAV_DB /M daily.cld /D -0 /C "cmd /c del @PATH"
FORFILES /P C:\ProgramData\.clamwin\db -M daily.cld /D 0 /C "cmd /c copy @PATH \\10.0.1.223\ClamAV_DB
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Because its UNC path, use PushD. Something like this.

```
PushD "\\10.0.1.223\ClamAV_DB" &&(
FORFILES -M daily.cld /D -0 /C "cmd /c del @file" 
) & PopD

FORFILES -P "C:\ProgramData\.clamwin\db" -M daily.cld /D -0 /C "cmd /c copy @file \\10.0.1.223\ClamAV_DB"
```

Comment: Whats the output? Any error messages? The command alone should be correct at least.

Comment: I think it is because I am accessing shared folder

Comment: Updated my example now. When accessing shared folder you can use PushD.

Comment: I also got it working using net use. Any difference between yours?

Comment: With mine you don't have to map up (net use) the shared folder. Its a lot handier in multiple settings.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working below.

```
net use A: \\10.0.1.43\ClamAV_DB
forfiles /P A:\ /M daily.cld /C "cmd /c del @PATH"
forfiles /P C:\ProgramData\.clamwin\db -M daily.cld /C "cmd /c copy @PATH A:\
```